# Javascript: Odd or Even script can't find my ERROR

Tags: javascript

For some reason the following code doesn't work but i don't see where it goes wrong...

```
for (number = 0; number <= 10; number ++1);{
  var odd = number%2;
  if (odd == true) {
    console.log(number + " = even");
  }
  else {
    console.log(number + " = oneven");
 }
```

Comment: `number ++1`? That doesn't look right.

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". What do you expect as a result? What your code does instead?

Comment: `number%2` returns a number. This makes `odd == true` not mean what you think it means.

Comment: It should go from 0 tot 10 and say wether its odd or even by every number

Comment: first line should be `for (var number = 0; number <= 10; number++) {`

Comment: if (number % 2) instead 
 of this 
  var odd = number%2;
  if (odd == true)

Comment: `number++` or `number + 1` but in this way you need to modify `number` somewhere inside this loop, in other way infinite loop will be there

Comment: The `;` in `for(...); {` makes the `for` execute an *empty* statement in each iteration. The following block (`{...}`) is not part of the `for` loop, it is only executed once after loop terminates.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 or 3 errors :

1. To increment, you need `++` and not `++1`
2. The `;` between `for` statement and `{` can cause syntax errors
3. You need to close your curly brackets at the end `{}`

Comment: Thank you! this solved it...
I didn't notice the curly bracket wasn't there at the end.. so frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `number++`.
2. Remove the misplaced semi-colon `);{`.
3. Correct your odd vs even logic (`number % 2 === 0` is even).
4. Close the `for` loop.

```js
for (number = 0; number <= 10; number++){
  if (number % 2 === 0) {
    console.log(number + " = even");
  } else {
    console.log(number + " = odd");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (number = 0; number <= 10; number++);{//fixed here
  var odd = number%2;
  if (odd == 0) {//fixed here
    console.log(number + " = even");
  }
  else {
    console.log(number + " = oneven");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

there are loads of errors

`++1`  <- unexpected number

`();` <- unexpected emicolon after if condition brackets

`}` <- for loop is missing closing bracket

so if the number is even `%` will return `0` which evaluates to false

so you also have to reverse your if

```
for (number = 0; number <= 10; number ++){
  var odd = number%2;
  if (odd == false) {
    console.log(number + " = even");
  }
  else {
    console.log(number + " = oneven");
 }
}
```